# Rowcount is not matching for similar query in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to check a row count of each table in my oracle production database. So, I am running 2 queries for my testing purpose.

1)  `select owner, table_name, num_rows 
    from all_tables 
    where OWNER = 'XYZ' and   TABLE_NAME = 'Application' 
    order by table_name asc;`

2) `select count(*) from XYZ.Application`

So, for the first query, I am getting result as 829 for the first query. While, for the second query, it is 836. So, can anyone help me to understand what I need to check to identify this discrepancy?

Thanks a lot guys for your response.
I would like to know how can we get exact count of row for all tables in single Query?

Answer (score 4):

`ALL_TABLES.NUM_ROWS` is the number that Oracle gathered as statistics.  It may be an estimate.  Or, it may be exact but outdated.

In no case can you look at it and conclude that you are seeing the exact number of rows that are currently in the table.

Your second query gives the exact number of rows currently in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The first query, from `all_tables`, is based on **statistics**, which are not necessarily up to date nor perfectly accurate.

The second query actually **scans the table data itself** and counts the rows. It will always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `LAST_ANALYZED` column of `ALL_TABLES`. That is the last time the stats were collected. It may not reflect the most current state of the table.

Answer (score 0):

NUM_ROWS reflects only the committed transactions. On the other hand COUNT(*) includes non-committed transactions from the session in which you run the COUNT(*) query.  Did you just INSERT seven rows, but didn't COMMIT them yet?